# Быстрое обратное геокодирование для веб-приложения

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, карты, openstreetmap, геокодирование

Т.е. на входе - пара координат (широта, долгота), на выходе - адрес объекта, если он есть в районе этих координат.

Сейчас пользуюсь геокодером Google, но на большом количестве точек он ощутимо притормаживает приложение, да и бесплатный ключ ограничивает функциональность.

Предложите бесплатную альтернативу, объекты - только Украина, Россия, Беларусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практически все сервисы имеют ограничения по количеству запросов к геокодеру.
Но кто вам мешает кешировать данные в своей БД.
Т.е. вы сохраняете данные в своей БД и обращаетесь к геокодеру только в том случае если этот адрес или объект еще не сохранен в вашей БД.

Например Яндекс не только допускает кеширование своих данных, а даже предлагает это практически стандартным решением.

Как у яндекса так и гугла операция геокодирования выполняется асинхронным запросом и при большом количестве точек у вас тормоза будут даже без ограничений сервиса.

Количество допустимых запросов в сутки прописано в пользовательском соглашении сервисов.

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатные API Яндекс карт позволяют в сутки делать не более 25000 запросов, и, как сказано выше - кешируйте данные в бд и обращайтесь к сервису только при необходимости получить новые данные